# Define $h_1(x) = f(g(x))$ and $h_2(x) = g(f(x)).$ Which of the following statements is correct?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the following functions

$f(x)= \begin{cases}  1 ,|x| \le 1 \\ 0 ,|x| > 1 \end{cases}$

and $g(x)= \begin{cases}  1 ,|x| \le 2 \\ 2 ,|x| > 2 \end{cases}$

Define $h_1(x) = f(g(x))$ and $h_2(x) = g(f(x)).$

Which of the following statements is correct?

$(A)$ $h_1$ and $h_2$ are continuous everywhere

$(B)$$ h_1$ is continuous everywhere and $h_2 $has discontinuity at $±1$

$(C)$ $h_2$ is continuous everywhere and $h_1$ has discontinuity at $±2$

$(D)$$ h_1$ has discontinuity at $±2$ and $h_2$ has discontinuity at $±1.$

My attempt  : $h_1(x) = 1$ , $h_2(x)= 2$, so option A) will be correct

Is its true ?

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

Comment: What makes you think $h_1(x)=1$? Consider $x_0=0$ and $x_1=3$. What's $h_1(x_0)$ and $h_1(x_1)$?

Comment: Hint: Check $h_1$ and $h_2$ values for the various ranges of $x$, especially where $f$ and $g$ has special behavior. In particular, check it for $x \leq -2, -2 \lt x \le -1, -1 \lt x \le 1, 1 \lt x \le 2, x \gt 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$h_2(x)=1$ for all $x$ (because $|f(x)| \leq 2$ for all $x$) and $h_1(x)=1$ for $|x| \leq 2$, $h_1(x)=0$ for $|x|>2$. So the correct option is (C).